Is there any tool to find out if a wave file is a interpolation of other?
I have two versions of a sample, one is 44.1 kHz and the other 96 kHz. Is there any tool to find out if the 96 version is a interpolation of the first? or how can I know it?

Start by looking at the spectrum.  If the 96k version has real spectral components above 22k, then there's a good chance it's not an up-sample.  If the spectrum cuts off at 22k, you cannot conclude either way, since the original source material may have been band-limited to 22k to begin with.
